# Slow Performance with Multi-threaded app - MySQL InnoDB

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, database-performance

My application is a java 1.7, multi-threaded application with MySQL 5.6 as the backend.

Application reads data from files and writes it to corresponding tables in multithreaded fashion. The performance is great when all threads are inserting records on different tables, but the application or rather inserts slows down as soon as all the threads starts inserting into the same table.

Each thread has its own prepared statement in batch mode with commit interval of 100 records. "rewriteBatchedStatements=true" property is already added during establishing the connection.

MySQL Driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
MySQL Storage engine: InnoDB

Any information / suggestions that can help improve performance will be highly appreciated.

Thanks...

Comment: Take thread dumps (`kill -3`) when you experiencing a slowdown and see for clues in dumps. It's likely, you'll need to take quite a few dumps during slowdown (20-100) to be able to see bottlenecks. There are Java profilers which make task of examining CPU distribution between JVM threads easier.

Comment: Without any further information, your guess is as good as ours. The number of variables in this equation is truly staggering...

Comment: @VictorSorokin: I used profiler (VisualVM) and also did the thread dump to monitor. I also used MySQL Server monitoring to observe the traffic and sql executed and also to check the sqls coming from java, MySQL traffic falls onces all the threads start hitting same table. Profiler did not show any wait or blocking on any of the threads. I was wondering if there is any settings either at MySQL level or during connection to improve the throughput.

Comment: @Minesh Of MySQL, I know (almost) nothing. You better ask on dba.stackexchange...